# CodeIgniter routing or .htaccess issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I just got a new CodeIgniter project and I think I have either routing problems or a .htaccess problem, the situation is like this:

The project is on a domain like this : www.example.com, and of course I need a copy of it in my /var/www/html/project folder because I don't want to work directly on the production server.

So I downloaded it and managed to get the front end part working perfectly from my localhost/project folder (actually I ended up using the ip address because if I use localhost it gows to www.localhost.com/project for some reason eventhough I edited the htacces file, but i can work with the ip).

Now the thing is something really weird is going in the back office part, I mean if I type 127.0.0.1/project/admin it gows to 127.0.0.1/project/admin/admin/login insteand of /admin/login.

And the links to all the css and js files are weird and can't figure out where this weirdness comes from.

Here are some pics:

[image: Weird css loading]

So as you can see in the picture above in the code it looks ok that's the path to the folder css/admin.css which is correct, but if you look in the console you can see that it tries to load admin/css/admin.css which of course it's not ok.

Now when I type in the adress bar : 1270.0.0.1/project/admin it goes to 127.0.0.1/admin/admin/ login and of course it goes 404 on me, but if I specify: 127.0.0.1/project/admin/login than it loads what you see in the picture above.

Below I will put the routes and stuff from the config file:

Routes:

```
$route['default_controller']    = "home";
$route['scaffolding_trigger']   = "";

//variables
$lang = "([a-zA-Z]{2}/)?";
$index_lang = "([a-zA-Z]{2}/?)?";

//admin
$route["admin"]             = "admin";
$route["admin/(.*)"]        = "admin/$1";

From the config:
$config['base_url']     = "";
$config['admin_url']    = $config['base_url']."admin/";
$config['base_path']    = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/project/";

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with CodeIgniter just a few times, but I think the cause of your problem is a) using relative paths or b) bad URL configuration

try to rewrite in config

```
$config['base_url']     = "";
```

to

```
$config['base_url']     = "http://localhost-or-ip/project-folder-name/";
```

another solution can be modifing your .htaccess file in root directory  - and of course modify your config.php to `$config['base_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` (or another original value)
you can try in .htacces rewrite this:

```
RewriteBase /
```

to

```
RewriteBase /project-folder-name/
```

both solutions(if they will work) are useable, but you should consider using Virtual Hosts and set your localhost domain url for example as: `my-domain.com.local` and using your `hosts` file for connecting this domain through localhost `127.0.0.1 my-domain.com.local`

Comment: Sir I wish to thank you for your help, changed the $config['base_url'] to the project folder. I was an idiot because i tried that but didn't put 'http://' in front of the address. Thank you very much!